# Properties of Lorentz transformation generator?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, special-relativity, linear-algebra

In chapter 2 of [Srednicki](http://web.physics.ucsb.edu/~mark/qft.html), the author defines:
$$
U(1+\delta \omega) = I +\frac{i}{2h}\delta \omega_{\mu \nu} M^{\mu \nu}
$$
where the $M^{\mu\nu}$s are hermitian operators and are the generators of the Lorentz group. Starting with the assumption that
$$
U(\Lambda)^{-1} U(\Lambda') U(\Lambda) = U(\Lambda^{-1} \Lambda' \Lambda)
$$
and letting
$$
\Lambda' = 1 + \delta \omega',
$$
the author is able to conclude (in his solutions) that:
$$
U(\Lambda)^{-1} (I + \frac{i}{2h}\delta \omega_{\mu \nu} M^{\mu \nu})U(\Lambda) = I + \frac{i}{2h}\delta \omega_{\mu \nu} U(\Lambda)^{-1} M^{\mu \nu} U(\Lambda)
$$

and

$$U(\Lambda^{-1}( 1 + \delta \omega') \Lambda) = I + \frac{i}{2h}\Lambda^{-1}\delta \omega_{\mu \nu} \Lambda M^{\mu \nu}.$$

Can someone explain how he came to this conclusion? What properties of $\omega$ and $M$ allow the $\omega$ to move to the left of the $U(\Lambda)$?

Answer (score 1):

I think the first is straightforward:
$$ U(\Lambda)^{-1} (I + \frac{i}{2h}\delta \omega_{\mu \nu} M^{\mu \nu})U(\Lambda) = U(\Lambda)^{-1} I U(\Lambda) + U(\Lambda)^{-1}  (\frac{i}{2h}\delta \omega_{\mu \nu} M^{\mu \nu}) U(\Lambda) = I + \frac{i}{2h}\delta \omega_{\mu \nu} U(\Lambda)^{-1} M^{\mu \nu} U(\Lambda)
$$

I think it doesn't matter the order: $\delta\omega_{\mu\nu}U(\Lambda)^{-1}M^{\mu\nu}U(\Lambda)=\delta\omega_{\mu\nu}\Lambda^{\mu}_{\rho}\Lambda^{\nu}_{\sigma}M^{\rho\sigma} = (\Lambda^{\mu}_{\rho}\Lambda^{\nu}_{\sigma}\delta\omega_{\mu\nu})M^{\rho\sigma}=(\Lambda^{-1}\delta\omega\Lambda)_{\rho\sigma}M^{\rho\sigma}$

For the second part:

$$
U(\Lambda^{-1}( 1 + \delta \omega') \Lambda) = U(\Lambda^{-1}\Lambda + \Lambda^{-1} \delta \omega'\Lambda ) = U(1 + \Lambda^{-1} \delta \omega'\Lambda ) = I + \frac{i}{2h}(\Lambda^{-1}\delta \omega \Lambda)_{\mu \nu} M^{\mu \nu}
$$

Comment: How does the δω end up outside the U^-1?

Comment: @cray_0n I answered too fast, but I think the reasoning is now  correct.

Comment: I think the answer to my question turns out to rest on the idea of a "similarity transformation." The key point is that $\omega$ and M are tensors, so the order should not change anything. The second part of my question, which I edited out, I realized was early morning silliness. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Any reason to introduce/drop the prime on omega in the last line?